# Job contract for a Freelancer

Tags: job-search, contracts, freelancing

I saw a job post last week and below are the details:

- Freelance client servicing job and they will pay per hour
- Freelance means working from home, however; there will be times that I need to meet some of their clients.
- There will be percentage if I get them new clients
- By the way, the company is new to market (like few months only) so they can only accommodate few full time workers only.
- Working hours should be 9am - 5pm

So for the mentioned job posting above - I applied; and later on the hiring manager told me I got the job. However, he didn't mention the salary, and position; and there was no even contract provided afterwards. He also asked my current salary for his own reference - but he didn't ask my salary expectation.

**So my question will be:**

1. Is it okay to ask for a job contract given that they will pay me per hour only?
2. If so, how should I ask for a job contract, including the following details:

Thanks!

Comment: it sounds like maybe a "sales" position??

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, of course it is OK to ask for a contract. That stipulates a lot more than just when and how you'll be paid.
2. "Please send me a copy of the contract" - you don't need to tell them what's in it - it's their contract.

However... I hope you haven't dropped a good job in favor of this zero-hours contract. I freelanced in different countries for many years, and the item in your question that alarmed me was the phrase "the company is new to market (like few months only) so they can only accommodate few full time workers only". This sounds like a company with a bad business plan and no cash flow - they're hoping to get clients, pass them onto you, and mark up your labour. All I can see are red flags here, and I don't think you should be getting your hopes up too high. Look for another position, and *make sure* that you don't invest more in this job than you can afford to lose.

Comment: No full time job as for now by the way and no offer yet as well for the same. This freelance job - he mentioned that it will be from 9-5 pm but will be paid per hour - which made me confused.